# Formatting Strings to Datetime using specific formats in Luxon

Tags: javascript, luxon

By now I used `moment-js` for time handling, but I want to switch to `Luxon`. But I have problems with the following implementation.

There is a textfield where you can enter a datetime in your locale time format, for instance `HH:mm` (24h format) or `hh:mm` (12h format). The used time format is stored in the variable `timeFormat`.

My solution with `moment-js`:

```
let timeFormat = 'HH:mm' // 'hh:mm a'
let textfield = document.querySelector('#input-time');
let timeString = textfield.value;
let dateTime = moment(timeString, timeFormat, true);

// Check if time is valid
if(dateTime.isValid() === false){
    return;
}
```

Using 12h-format:

- `11:00 am`, `09:43 pm` are **valid**.
- `11:00`, `21:43` are **invalid**.

Using 24h-format:

- `11:00 am`, `09:43 pm` are **invalid**.
- `11:00`, `21:43` are **valid**.

How can I aprove obtain a similar solution with `Luxon`? My biggest issue is to get a similar function to `moment(timeString, timeFormat, true)`, so formatting a String into a Datetime using a specific format, for instance 12h/24-format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`fromFormat`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromformat) method

> Create a DateTime from an input string and format string. Defaults to en-US if no locale has been specified, regardless of the system's locale.

Example:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const inputs = ['11:00 am', '09:43 pm', '11:00', '21:43'];
const formats = ['HH:mm', 'hh:mm a'];

const checkTime = (timeString, fmt) => 
  DateTime.fromFormat(timeString, fmt).isValid


for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
  for (j=0; j<formats.length; j++) {
    console.log(`${inputs[i]} with format '${formats[j]}' is valid? ` + checkTime(inputs[i], formats[j]) );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.25.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

Have a look at [For Moment users](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/moment) section of the manual for good reference to migrate from momentjs to Luxon.